# Not able to Close Sticky Notes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

[Sticky Notes](http://jsfiddle.net/bdzht7p6/79/)

Below is my fiddle code in which on comment click sticky Note gets appear but when I click on Right Hand Side Close Button Close Button Click Event not getting fired. I have checked by putting alert popup whether remove sticky note event getting fired or not.

```js
var config = {
    allowedContent: true
};

CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', config);

$('#button').click(function() {
    var dummy = CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].getSelection().getSelectedText(); 
});
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#button").click(
            function () {
            var currentSelectedRange = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection().getRanges();
        if(currentSelectedRange && currentSelectedRange.length > 0 && currentSelectedRange[0].startOffset != currentSelectedRange[0].endOffset ){
     var markup =
        '<div class="box note background-gray">' +
        '<div class="box-header">' + 
        '<span class="date-time"></span>' +
        '<a href="#" class="right remove hidden">&times;</a>' +
        '</div><textarea class="note-text"></textarea></div>';

    var spawn = function () {
        $("body").append(makeNote($(markup)));
    };

    var remove = function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    };

    var resizeTextArea = function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var spaceToGrab = 60;
        self.find('.note-text').height(self.height() - 45);
    };

    var hideButtons = function (element) {
        $(element).find("a").hide();
    };

    var showButtons = function (element) {
        $(element).find("a").show();
    };

    var save = function (id, value, position) {
        console.log(id); // position
        console.log(value);
        console.log(position);
    };

    var makeNote = function (element) {
        var today = new Date();
        var Time = '';
        if (today.getHours() <= 12) {
            Time += ' AM';
        } //end if
        if (today.getHours() > 12) {
            Time += ' PM';
        } //end if
        var timeStamp = today.getDate() + '/' + today.getMonth() + '/' + today.getFullYear() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() +  Time;
    
        var $note = $(element);
         
         $(".note.box").add($note).attr('id', function(i, id){
           return i;
         });
        $note.resizable({
            handles: "se"
        });
        $note.draggable({
            handle: ".box-header"
        });
        $note.find('.date-time').text(timeStamp);

        $text = $note.find('textarea');
        $text.focusout(function (e) {
            save($(this).oid, $(this).val(), $(this).parent().position());
        });
        var comments = {};

       $note.click(function () {
            $(this).find('textarea').focus();
            if(comments[this.id]){
              var sel = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection()
              sel.selectRanges(comments[this.id]);
            }else{
              comments[this.id] = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getSelection().getRanges();
            }
        });
           $note.mouseover(function () {
            showButtons(this);
        });
        $note.mouseout(function () {
            hideButtons(this);
        });

        $note.find(".add").click(spawn);
       $note.find(".remove").click(remove);
      
        $note.resize(resizeTextArea);
        hideButtons($note);
        return $note;
    };

    $(".note").each(function (i, e) {
        makeNote(e);
    });

    spawn();
}
            }            
        );
    });
```

```css
.box {

    min-width: 100px;

    min-height: 100px;

    margin: 20px;

    /* display: ; */
position: absolute;
top: -200px;
left: 40px;
    width: 200px;

}

.note {

    /* box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset; */

    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #888;

    background-color: lime;

}
.date-time {
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.box-header {

    min-height: 30px;

    background-color: #e0e0e0;

    text-align: right;

    line-height: 30px;

}

.box-header a {

    display: block;

    margin: 4px;

    width: 20px;

    height: 20px;

    line-height: 20px;

    font-size: 24px;

    text-align: center;

    font-weight: bolder;

    font-family:"Helvetica Neue LT", "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #666;

    border-radius: 5px;

}

.box-header a:link, .box-header a:visited {

    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;

}

.box-header a:hover, .box-header a:active {

    border: 1px solid #aaa;

    background-color: #ccc;

}

.left {

    float: left;

}

.right {

    float: right;

}

.hidden {

    display: none;

}

.note-text {

    margin: 0;

    background: none;

    border: none;

    font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";

    font-size: 24px;

    width: 100%;

    font-style: italic;

    resize: none;

    overflow: auto;

    outline: none;

    padding: 5px;

}

.background-gray {

    background: #ffffff;

    /* Old browsers */

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* FF3.6+ */

    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #e0e0e0));

    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* Opera 11.10+ */

    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* IE10+ */

    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);

    /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e0e0e0', GradientType=0);

    /* IE6-9 */

}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.6/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Comment</button>
<textarea id="editor1">
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="64" style="DISPLAY: block; COLOR: #2980b9; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px" width="342"><a href="http://www.codinghorror.com" style="LINE-HEIGHT: 64px; WIDTH: 100%; DISPLAY: inline-block; FONT-FAMILY: arial, verdana, sans-serif; FONT-SIZE: 24px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none; text-transform: uppercase;" target="" title=""><span style="COLOR: #2980b9">Styled Link</span> </a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `makenote` function is not identical with your other fiddle that you had posted yesterday. I have made them identical now and it is working fine.

**Here is the working DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bdzht7p6/81/

Hope this helps!